# Accessing Height, Width properties of a control is slower in C#

Tags: c#, performance, compact-framework

I found some surprising results while drawing some shapes in .Net Compact Framework.

Method1 and Method2 draws some rectangles but Method1 is faster then Method2, here is the code:

Method1:

```
int height = Height;
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
  barYPos = Helper.GetPixelValue(Point1, Point2, data[i]);

  barRect.X = barXPos;
  barRect.Y = barYPos;
  barRect.Height = height - barYPos;
  //
  //rects.Add(barRect);
  _gBmp.FillRectangle(_barBrush, barRect);
  //
  barXPos += (WidthOfBar + DistanceBetweenBars);
}
```

Method2:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
  barYPos = Helper.GetPixelValue(Point1, Point2, data[i]);

  barRect.X = barXPos;
  barRect.Y = barYPos;
  barRect.Height = Height - barYPos;
  //
  //rects.Add(barRect);
  _gBmp.FillRectangle(_barBrush, barRect);
  //
  barXPos += (WidthOfBar + DistanceBetweenBars);
}
```

The only difference between two is in `Method1` I am storing the `Height` of the control in a local variable.

Can anyone please explain the reason and some guidelines for drawings in .Net Compact Framework?

Answer (score 3):

Method 2 is slower because you're accessing the Height property at each iteration of your for loop. This property may cause some time consuming calculations, and putting it in a local variable outside the loop acts as a cache.

Answer (score 1):

A call to a property in C# has more associated cost than it would directly accessing a variable in memory; as properties are generated as methods with a backing field in the background (and/or worse.. perhaps it queries something else!)

If your application is indeed single threaded and you can afford to cache it, do so. Avoid properties in tight loops.

Answer (score 0):

I believe thats because you access `Height`- `data.Lenght` amoutns of times. and in the first methood you only initalize it once.